# Where to keep "currentUser" globally accessible

Tags: redux

Almost every object in my state tree needs to have the following fields:

- createdByGuid
- createdAt
- modifiedAt

The date fields are easy to add in the action creators. There seems to be consensus that action creators are the place where impureness are allowed, i.e. `new Date()`.

But the currently logged in user is not easily fetched since this data lives in another slice of the state.

Example state:

```
profile
  data
    guid
    firstname
    ...
media
  items
    0: guid, createdByGuid, ...
    1: guid, createdByGuid, ...
drawings
  items
    ...
```

When a MEDIA_ADD action is dispatched I want the action creator to augment the dispatched data with createdById. Current user needs to be fetched from `profile.data.guid`.

I don't want to bring the state into my action creator. Instead I can use a thunk to get hold of the state via getState(). But this seems to be a clumsy way of getting hold of a simple guid constant (constant for this session). It becomes more clumsy when essentially all of my action creators for adding data to the state needs to be thunks.

I'm inclined to create a separate global singleton object to hold this data and bring this dependency into all of my action creator modules. This seems to be a lot less disturbing dependency in terms of for example testing.

I suppose most Redux users has about the same question regarding current user. What is a good solution?

I'm working in react-native, but I suppose the question applies to most Redux applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is interested, I went the singleton way with this. Not a true singleton per definition, but it suits my needs.

When a user logs in I handle this in an asynchronous action creator (a thunk). The thunk calls setGlobalCurrentUser() after successfully authenticating the user with the server.

To get hold of the current user I only have to import currentUserGuid() from currentUser.js and I don't end up in a dependency hell.

**currentUser.js:**

```
let _currentUserGuid;

export function currentUserGuid() {
  if(!_currentUserGuid) throw new Error('currentUserGuid:: No logged in user')
  return _currentUserGuid;
}

export function setGlobalCurrentUser(user) {
  if(user) {
    _currentUserGuid = user.get('guid')
  } else {
    _currentUserGuid = null
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you maintain the state through sessions, like a 'keep me logged' feature?

Comment: I’m using Redux. The logged in user and the access token are saved to disk along with the rest of the Radux store via asyncStorage. When the store is rehydrated from disk I call setGlobalCurrentUser so I have access to userId without having to select it from Redux.

Comment: Also... I have since moved away from thunks and I only use Redux-Saga instead.